# access googledrive or icloud from app using codenameone

Tags: codenameone

I want to manually allow user to save the the data from app directly to google drive or iCloud. Suppose, I have an image and when user clicks save button he need to get option to save to icloud or google drive anyone of these in the iOS device. How can i achieve this in codenameone are there any plugin, api or library avaliable? As goggle provided google-api-services for android application. How I achieve this in iOS.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Doing this with an image should be easy. Just use the share feature in Codename One:

```
// will return false on the simulator but work in iOS/Android
if(Display.getInstance().isNativeShareSupported()) {
     Display.getInstance().share("", fileSystemPathToImage, imageMimeType);
}
```

Suggestions of where to save should be based on the things available in your device e.g. Facebook, iCloud, Drive, Dropbox etc.